# Changing of existing text in console window

Tags: c, c99, c89, c11

Sometimes, when I install programs, I see progress bar in console window (or other, dynamic changing text). It is  displayed, and changing in the same row of string. When I use `printf` or other function, I write next text, but I can't modify in console window already existing text. How can I do it through C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for this kind of effects is to use the caret return `\r` character that lets you write over the previous line.

---

If you'd like to have direct access to the console's buffer (i.e. writing in specific X/Y position instead of line-by-line), then you're probably looking for a helper library like `pdcurses`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep using printf and have an easy go at "*changing*" the text, use `\r` which is carriage return on linux.
It won't work on MAC though, because it means newline.

If you do this, I'd advise using [ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) to hide the caret to prevent flickering and an ugly effet.

If you want a better way of manipulating text on-screen you can have a look at [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)